# How to find the latter half of a pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find the latter half of patterns of the following template:

```
foo/BAR
```

'BAR' is the one I'm trying to retrieve. I tried with something like:

```
\b(foo)/([a-zA-Z]+)
```

This works fine, but this also matches `http://foo/BAR` - which I don't want.

I also tried

```
\\s(foo)/([a-zA-Z]+)
```

but this doesnt match when the line starts with foo/BAR. (I'm using java.util.regex)

Comment: As written, the two regexes look identical to me.  Also, what about the bad example makes it something you don't want?  Is it because foo isn't at the beginning of the line?  Because of the double slash?  Something else?

Comment: Can you provide some more examples? Is there anything with slashes coming after `BAR` or not?

Comment: What about the end of the token? I.e. given "foo/BA$" should it be found and return "foo/BA" or should it not be found at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(^|\s)foo/([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Comment: maybe `(?:^|\s)foo/(a-zA-Z)+`? `\b` isn't working well for the OP here.

Comment: `\b` allows special characters before foo, as in `http://foo/BAR`. Space, which was your original choice, seems right here. Also, the start of the line is matched by `\b`, so `^|` is redundant.

Comment: This demonstrates nicely that that you can, mostly, use logical operators with metacharacters and character escapes. That allows for much more possibilities with regexes.

Comment: (a-zA-Z) should really be [a-zA-Z]

Comment: Antony, this is very close to what I want. Hence accepting this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you define a full "foo/BAR" token as both preceeded and followed by whitespace (or begin/end of the line)

I.e. it would find "abc", "XyZ", and "def" in

```
"foo/abc 123 hhh foo/XyZ http://foo/BAR foo foo/ foo/ghi% foo/def"
```

then you want

```
(?:^|\s)foo/([a-zA-Z]+)(?:$|\s)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
^(foo)/([a-zA-Z]+)
```

or

```
(?<!http://)(foo)/([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Comment: Are you suggesting two different regexes and ORing them? For some restriction, my regex is placed in an external file, and I can specify only one combined regex

Answer (score 1):

\b is a word boundary, ^ is a start of line marker

```
^foo/(\w+)
```

Comment: start of line is not the only place the author expects foo/BAR to be

Comment: \w includes national characters, which is supposedly not what the author expects

Comment: Regarding where he wants to match it, I might have misread the question. When he said he doesn't want to match `http://foo/BAR`, I couldn't come to another conclusion besides not wanting it at start of line.

Regarding \w, it was a suggestion (in hindsight, I should have mentioned it), he seems to have the know how to revert it if need be.

I'm thinking you and Jordan understood it right by using this at the start: `(?:^|\s)`